# how to concatenate new arraylist to existing arraylist during scroll(pagination) and show to recyclerview android

Tags: android, arraylist, pagination

i am showing arraylist getting from server to recyclerview.now i added pagination, its working fine and showing new list in recyclerview replacing previous list. but i want pagination like new list will concatenate to the existing list and show merged list(like facebok if i scrolldown after showing certain items it added new items to the list, concatenate with last list and show all the items) in recyclerview.

adapter constructor :

```
public NewsFeedAdapter (ArrayList<NewsFeedClass> newsFeedClassArrayList, Context context ){

        this.context=context;
        this.newsFeedClassArrayList=newsFeedClassArrayList;

    }
```

adapter code:

```
public class NewsFeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsFeedAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    private static ArrayList<NewsFeedClass> newsFeedClassArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    private NewsFeedClass newsFeedClass;
    private String videoId="zDlMVlUriLw";
    private int totalLikeWow;  // total like,dislike,wow,bleh count;
    AsyncTaskClass asyncTaskClass;
    private NameShowWho_SharedPostAdapter nameShowWhoSharedPostAdapter;
    NameShowWho_SharedPost_class nameShowWhoSharedPost_class;
    private int changeValue;//like ad/less on button click
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    int previousItemsSize;


    public NewsFeedAdapter (ArrayList<NewsFeedClass> newsFeedClassArrayList, Context context ){

        this.context=context;
//        this.newsFeedClassArrayList=newsFeedClassArrayList;

        addItems(newsFeedClassArrayList);

    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {





        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_adapter,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsFeedClassArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    private void addItems(List<NewsFeedClass> newItems) {
        previousItemsSize = newsFeedClassArrayList.size();
        // Append the new items to the old items
        newsFeedClassArrayList.addAll(newItems);
        // Notify the adapter about the newly added items
        notifyItemRangeInserted(previousItemsSize, newItems.size());
    }
}
```

please i need help me on this issue. i have tried but did not find any.

Comment: Please share your adapter code here?

Comment: updated the code.,.,.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to achieve this:

1. Create a new empty List in your adapter class constructor.
2. Add a new public method to update the adapter data with new items.

For example:

```
private List<String> mItems; // Demo data source

// Adapter constructor creates an empty list
public MyAdapter() {
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addItems(List<String> newItems) {
    int previousItemsSize = mItems.size();
    // Append the new items to the old items
    mItems.addAll(newItems);
    // Notify the adapter about the newly added items
    notifyItemRangeInserted(previousItemsSize, newItems.size());
}
```

Now, When you need to add a new set of items - just call the `AddItems()` method.

Comment: i saw examples like this but i couldnt understand well and implement that.can you give me in more details plz

Comment: from where to call addItems() ?

Comment: Every time you have new data you want to add to the list call addItems().

Comment: i have called the method from constructor but its not working

Comment: addItems(list) method should call from your activity or fragments, where you get data from web and set via this method.

Answer (score 0):

You just add item in your adapter like this

```
public NewsFeedAdapter (ArrayList<NewsFeedClass> newsFeedClassArrayList, Context context ){

    this.context=context;
    this.newsFeedClassArrayList=newsFeedClassArrayList;

}
```

after when you get new record then simple to add as below. you need to do this things in you `Activity/Fragment` class where you can set your adapter in you recyclerview.

```
adapter.addItems(newsFeedClassArrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `addAll(`) to add data to existing list after receiving data from server `originalList.addAll(listFromServer);`
and then notify your adapter.

Let me know if it helps.